# Mysql primary and unique key (prevent duplicate data)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this scenario and am trying to figure out how to stop the insertion of duplicate data into the db.

I have table `log` and include row:

> device id , time (this is not the time insert but its the time the logs occur) , content

Each user can submit from their device id with data example

> 123ABC , 2013-11-27 01:19:37 , sample text

Each user can submit up to 500 logs from a device using xml protocol.
So from control panel page, I can select user (from this device id) and viewing total of logs they submit (distinct device id, time) so I only see their unique logs, for example, 400 unique logs.
But in the back end mysql they have up to 2000 record logs and all of them duplicated 5  times from 400 unique logs.

- I can't make device id as unique because 1 device can submit multiple times and it will stop insert data because each time can be same device id.
- I can't combine unique (device id and time). i thought this would work but the data won't insert at all; it rejects my query. Each data have unique time, content but not device id...

How can I make this work?

If I want each user to continue submit data logs, but not duplicate ones and only unique data logs from a same device id.

If I select Time and Content only as unique index. It will fail sometimes if multiple device submit same time of logs has occur and content is the same...

How can I make it unique for each device id but not other device id.

Comment: and what you have in your code? You should prevent duplicates in your code before inserting them in DB.. can you add/have user id in that database table?

Comment: I did, but each user have a reset button that every time click on it, it will resubmit the logs all the way from beginning. Reset button is like reset the time set, back last 6 months so it will flush all the logs from last 6 months again. Also, to prevent lost logs, our codes on device resubmit the data every time ping out or time out on internet connection, so this could be duplicate re insert too.. I couldnt figure this out. Seem like out of option

Comment: I think the problem is that this requirement is not clear to you.
In that case, you cannot be clear about the implementation. Can you explain in plain words what should be unique?

Comment: you should at least have some kind of user_id in that table...?

Comment: User id is device id. Unique data is content and on each device id and time. But also sometime, other device can have same time and content also but difference device id

Comment: For example : 123ABC , 2013-11-27 01:19:37 , text 1    |   123ABC , 2013-11-28 01:19:37 , text 2    |  123ABC , 2013-11-29 01:19:37 , text 3  | other user: 456ABC , 2013-11-27 01:19:37 , text 1 | 456ABC , 2013-11-28 01:19:37 , text 2  |   456ABC , 2013-11-29 01:19:37 , text 3

Comment: As you can see, there are are 2 diff user submit same time logs and same content, this is acceptable because its unique on each user. But if the same user for example 123ABC , 2013-11-27 01:19:37 , text 1 | 123ABC , 2013-11-28 01:19:37 , text 2 | 123ABC , 2013-11-29 01:19:37 , text 3  keep repeating 123ABC , 2013-11-27 01:19:37 , text 1 | 123ABC , 2013-11-28 01:19:37 , text 2 | 123ABC , 2013-11-29 01:19:37 , text 3. Then i want only the unique to be insert

Comment: you should make some filtering criteria of your own, say a user can only log same data once a day

Comment: Combine all 3 columns into a unique key.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why a regular composite unique index on both columns wouldn't work;

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
  log_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  device_id  VARCHAR(32),
  time       DATETIME,
  content    VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_logs ON logs (device_id, time);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c456/1).

```
-- First insert
INSERT INTO logs (device_id, time, content) VALUES 
  ('123ABC', '2013-11-27 01:19:37', 'sample text');

-- New time, ok    
INSERT INTO logs (device_id, time, content) VALUES 
  ('123ABC', '2013-11-27 01:19:47', 'sample text');

-- Duplicate of #1, fails
INSERT INTO logs (device_id, time, content) VALUES 
  ('123ABC', '2013-11-27 01:19:37', 'sample text');
```

Comment: I know that the requirement indicates that he wants to prevent dups. However, to behave like a log you shouldn't. In addition, the unique (any) index performance hit is unnecessary. But kudos for the auto-increment surrogate key. Last thing, you may want to note of the time zone of the device that sends the log.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

- create table with fields `batch_id` and `device_id`
- create MD5 hash from data user submittes (whole xml)
- add record to created table with that MD5 hash and device id

then you can just check if content is already submitted before by checking content hash against database hashes.

Comment: I don't have permission to edit the code on client, but only on db. Is there a solution on create MD5 has on a column selective instead ? then create index unique for that hash ?

Comment: No, You should have access to php code that is inserting the data if you want it to work like you described.